# How to transfer file chunks for large file download and reconstruct it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I need to download large files using files chunks for which JAVA spring server is developed and files are recived at UI via REST api. Looking for solution to join all chunks in javascript

Comment: This is two questions in one. One for Java, and one for JavaScript. Please may you split it up and provide a [mcve] for each?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about your requirement but hope this will help you

first you need to fetch the file using a fetch call inside a `async` function

`response = await fetch(url);`

then after that you will be able to get a reader from the response
`const reader = response.body.getReader();`

you can track the fetch by measuring the progress for that store the total file size

`const contentLength = +response.headers.get('Content-Length');`

in ordre to track the recieved bytes
`let receivedLength = 0;`

to store the chunks recieved

`let chunks = []; // array of received binary chunks (comprises the body)`

after that do a while loop which will run endlessly

```
while(true) {
          const {done, value} = await reader.read();

          if (done) {
            break;
          }

          chunks.push(value);
          receivedLength += value.length;
            
          let compleated = Math.round(receivedLength/contentLength*100);

          console.log(`Received ${receivedLength} of ${contentLength}`)
        }

 after the while loop has broken you can check if the transfer is fully completed or not
```

then you can create a blob from the array which we stored our chunks of data

`let blob = new Blob(chunks);`

then you can use this blob

Comment: i am not really familiar  with this but this is kinda worked for me while dealing with big files. i hope there are more efficient ways to solve this